# Magento API endSession() return not correct value <endSessionResponseParam>

Tags: magento-1.7

Calling the web service endSession(),  returns a message without value.
Magento 1.7.0.2

**Request XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="urn:Magento">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:endSessionParam>
      <sessionId>580529f990xxxxxxxxxx97d873c9fc0</sessionId>
    </ns1:endSessionParam>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

**Result Magento 1.7.0.2**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:ns1="urn:Magento">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:endSessionResponseParam/>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Magento ver. 1.9.0.1 return correct response

**Result Magento 1.9.0.1**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:ns1="urn:Magento">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:endSessionResponseParam>
            <result>true</result>
        </ns1:endSessionResponseParam>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

How can I fix this bug ?

```
//MAGENTO WS-I COMPILANCE MODE TRUE
$proxy_wsi = new SoapClient('http://magxxxto.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl', array('trace' => 1));
$session_id = $proxy_wsi->login((object)array('username' => 'apikeyUsername', 'apiKey' => 'apikeyPassword'));
var_dump($session_id);
$tmp=$session_id->result;

$flag=$proxy_wsi->endSession($session_id->result);
var_dump($flag);
exit;
```

return flag empty stdClass but no with Magento 1.9